# Spring Boot no argument Service constructor without autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying out spring boot and I have setup a test which autowires my PetService and calls the "createTest" method which in turn autowires the "PetRepository" and calls it's CreateTest save method.

My test works just fine. I have an situatinos which requires me to be able to call the PetService createTest method and construct it without the petRepository argument (no autowiring).

How would I change my implementation to allow this? Perhaps I could create a PetRepositoryImpl and then instantiate that in the PetService constructor thus avoiding the autowiring ?

```
@SpringBootTest
class SjdbcDemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private PetService petService;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("test");
        petService.createTest();
    }
    
}
```

PetService

```
@PetService
package com.example.epsys.SJDBC_DEMO;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Service
public class PetService{

    private final PetRepository petRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PetService(PetRepository petRepository) {
        this.petRepository = petRepository;
    }

    public void createTest(){
        Pet pet2 = Pet.create( "Dog", LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 30));
        System.out.println(pet2.toString());
        petRepository.save(pet2);
    }


}
```

PetRepository

```
package com.example.epsys.SJDBC_DEMO;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PetRepository extends CrudRepository<Pet, Long> {

}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? There is no need for the `@Autowired` on the constructor (not since Spring 4.3 anyway) and the `@Repository` is pretty useless as well. Still I'm unclear whatyou are trying to achieve/want to test.

Comment: I am wanting to bundle my app in a FAT jar and then from another APP running on the same JVM (which needs to remain separate ) instantiate PetService without the need for the PetRepository as an argument.

Comment: The `PetService` needs it, why would you want to create an instance without the repository, without it, it won't function.

Comment: Yes. I was hoping that there was some way of way of instantiating the petRepository in the petService without setting it in the constructor. So PetService can be instantiated without the need to provide the petRepository. This would allow us to tall the PetService from an external library.

Comment: What you are basically trying to do is breaking IoC. This will not work and neither is it a good idea, because to create a petRepository, you need some other classes (which again, you would have to autowire) without any gain.

Comment: Import Lombok into your project and use  class annotation that will create your constructor from behind: 
https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html